# How can I connect a SKScene to a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skscene

In the main ViewController class usually called 'GameViewController' there's this part in the code that can use 'GameScene' classes and you can add Nodes or Labels. This is the part in 'GameViewController.m'

> ```
> - (void)viewDidLoad
> {
>     [super viewDidLoad];
>
>     // Configure the view.
>     SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
>     skView.showsFPS = YES;
>     skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
>     /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
>     skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;
>
>     // Create and configure the scene.
>     GameScene *scene = [GameScene unarchiveFromFile:@"GameScene"];
>     scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
>
>     // Present the scene.
>     [skView presentScene:scene];
> }
> ```

I created another UIViewController class called 'ViewController' and a SKScene class called 'testSceneClass'. I tried doing this in 'ViewController.m' class:

> ```
> - (void)viewDidLoad
> {
>     [super viewDidLoad];
>     //[ViewController addChild: test];
>
>     // Configure the view.
>     SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
>     skView.showsFPS = YES;
>     skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
>     /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
>     skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;
>
>     // Create and configure the scene.
>     testSceneClass *scene = [testSceneClass unarchiveFromFile:@"testSceneClass"];
>     scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
>
>     // Present the scene.
>     [skView presentScene:scene];
> }
> ```

But it gives me the error "No known class method for selector 'unarchiveFromFile'" And I copied pretty much everything from the SKScene and UIViewController so I don't know what is wrong. But when I run it, it crashes and this is the reason:

> reason: '-[UIView setShowsFPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance

When I add a Exception Breakpoint it showed up on this line.

> `skView.showsFPS = YES;`

Then when I comment it, it shows a error on the next line, you can look at it in the 'ViewController.m' file I showed above. After I commented all those, an error showed up on this line:

> ```
> NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:nodePath
>                                           options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe
>                                             error:nil];
> ```
>
> and so on...

Any help?? (Sorry I added so much lol)

Comment: Did you setup your view controller so its view is an `SKView`?

Comment: Both ViewControllers in the '.h' file are 'ViewControllerName : UIViewController' @rmaddy

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. Is your view controller setup through a storyboard or xib or all through code?

Comment: ohh oops, well I added a ViewController in the 'Main.storyboard' and I put the class for that ViewController as 'ViewController' @rmaddy

Comment: OK, in Interface Builder, update that view controller's view to be of type `SKView` instead of the default `UIView` (just like the view controller that works).

Comment: Ok, where do I change that? I didn't see any options in the main.storyboard.. @rmaddy

Comment: I don't use IB but I think you need to select the view controller's view and then poke around in the properties inspector on the right for a place you can set the classname.

Comment: Ok, well under that tab there's something called 'Module' i'm not sure what that is but I haven't seen anything that describes it using 'SKView' or 'UIView' @rmaddy

Comment: Do you just code everything instead of using the storyboard? Which is easier? @rmaddy